# How to exclude certain paths from routing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a project where all paths are routed through the same /index page, however this directs images/css/js files through the same page. In the example below, I am wondering how would I exclude those resources (i.e. /images/*, /js/*, /css/*, etc) from being routed to the /index page?

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/index", "{*url}");
});
```

Comment: `this directs images/css/js files through the same page.` Do you mean that all request(s) to static files are mapped to index page?

Comment: The example I showed works great for us. all our pages get routed through /index and the page content gets loaded based on the path. However, we do not want files that are not pages to be routed to /index. So I am wondering how to modify that to exclude certain paths, for example, any path that begins with "/images/"

Answer (score 1):

Using this regex, I was able to route everything except if the path has "images/" and it seems to work:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Index", "{*url:regex(^(?!images/).*$)}");
```